# Using itertools to generate an exponential binary space

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-itertools

I am interested in generating all binary combination of `N` variables without having to implement a manual loop of iterating N times over N and each time looping over `N/2` and so on.

Do we have such functionality in python?

E.g:

I have `N` binary variables:

```
pool=['A','B','C',...,'I','J']
len(pool)=10
```

I would like to generate `2^10=1024` space out of these such as:

```
          [A B C ... I J]
iter0    = 0 0 0 ... 0 0
iter1    = 0 0 0 ... 0 1
iter2    = 0 0 0 ... 1 1
...
iter1022 = 1 1 1 ... 1 0
iter1023 = 1 1 1 ... 1 1
```

You see that I don't have repetitions here, each variable is enabled once per each of these iter's sequences. How can I do that using Python's `itertools`?

Comment: Use [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) with the `repeat` parameter

Comment: @lazydog. That won't work, tried that already. btw, I don't have repetition here. E.g., variable `A` should be enabled once per each sequence.

Comment: Then what are examples of your _actual_ expected output here? Be clear. For example, does `iter1` in your table translate to `'J'`? Is `iter2` supposed to represent `'IJ'`? Will just `'I'` be part of the output?

Comment: my expected output is in the question. Yes. but for completeness, I would like to have the 0s and 1s to make sure it went fine.

Comment: Then it what way does `itertools.product` fail to produce your expected output?

Comment: I didn't know I had to iter over (0,1), I was itering over the variables themselve and thats why I could not get the expected results.

Comment: I see. I'm sorry, I should have been more explicit in my initial comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`itertools.product` with the `repeat` parameter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) is the simplest answer:

```
for A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J in itertools.product((0, 1), repeat=10):
```

The values of each variable will cycle fastest on the right, and slowest on the left, so you'll get:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
```

etc. This may be recognizable to you: It's just the binary representation of an incrementing 10 bit number. Depending on your needs, you may actually want to just do:

```
for i in range(1 << 10):
```

then mask `i` with `1 << 9` to get the value of `A`, `1 << 8` for `B`, and so on down to `1 << 0` (that is, `1`) for `J`. If the goal is just to print them, you can even get more clever, by binary stringifying and then using `join` to insert the separator:

```
for i in range(1 << 10):
    print(' '.join('{:010b}'.format(i)))
    # Or letting print insert the separator:
    print(*'{:010b}'.format(i)) # If separator isn't space, pass sep='sepstring'
```

Comment: Thanks @ShadowRanger. Then I should print(A,...,J) to have to have the complete sequence. right?

Comment: @Amir: Yeah. You don't *have* to unpack them by name if you don't need them individually; `for bits in itertools.product((0, 1), repeat=10):` followed by `print(*bits)` would produce the same output as unpacking and explicitly naming them all in the `print` call.

Comment: @ShahowRanger, Could you explain what does `:010b` represent here?

Comment: @Amir: It's from the [format specification mini-language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec). The `:` is necessary to introduce the format spec (you could put a `0` before it to explicitly say you want the 0th positional arg, but it's not needed on 2.7+). The `0` says pad with zeroes, the `10` says it must pad to a 10 character width (so `0` produces 10 zeroes, not one), and the `b` says to expect an integer and format it as its bit representation (aka the base 2 representation).

Comment: @ShahowRanger. Sry again. So if I want to do a job for variable(i) on each of those occurrences of 1 in the i's position, how can I use your code? Say if we had only 6 variable and a sequence was: (0 1 0 0 0 1), I would like to do sth like A[1]=X and A[5]=Y (or any task), since only the position 2 and 6 
 on this sequence are only 1.

Comment: @Amir: So what would all the other values in `A` be under this scenario? I strongly suspect you're asking a question sufficiently complex to warrant a separate question, but it's a little unclear what your goal is. I suggest trying to make it work on your own, and if it fails, asking a new question including a [MCVE]; you can't expect people to write all the code for you.